# why does calculation changes in order taken

Tags: postgresql

why does this query miscalculates the colum for ordertaken?? is it about the groupings>

```
       SELECT t2.employeeid, t1.firstname || ' ' || t1.lastname as fullname,
       sum(t3.quantity*t4.price) as totalsales,
       COUNT(t2.orderid) AS ordertaken, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.customerid) AS uniquecustomercount   
       from  employees as t1
       join orders as t2 on t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid
       join order_details as t3 on t2.orderid = t3.orderid
       join products as t4 on t4.productid = t3.productid 
       group by t2.employeeid, fullname
```

correct computation for column ordertaken

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a distinct count for both counts:

```sql
SELECT
    t2.employeeid,
    t1.firstname || ' ' || t1.lastname AS fullname,
    SUM(t3.quantity*t4.price) AS totalsales,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.orderid) AS ordertaken,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.customerid) AS uniquecustomercount
FROM employees AS t1
INNER JOIN orders AS t2 ON t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid
INNER JOIN order_details AS t3 ON t2.orderid = t3.orderid
INNER JOIN products AS t4 ON t4.productid = t3.productid 
GROUP BY t2.employeeid, fullname;
```

The distinct counts are required on the counts from the `orders` table because the joins to `order_details` and `products` may duplicate a given order record, magnifying the count.